# MSdeploy : Web transformation files and parameterization mutually exclusive?

Tags: msdeploy

I created a transformation file "Web.Release.config"  with a specific configuration (appsetings,connectionstring, bindings). In the same project, I created the parameters.xml file as well, and added a couple of parameters of my configuration (app setings, bindings).
After this I built the deployment package "mypackage.zip."

I went and modified the setparameters.xml file with the intention of deploying mypackage.zip using a different configuration to the one specified in the transformation file "Web.Release.config". But when I deployed the package, msdeploy ignores the parameterization, even though I specify to use the setparameter.xml during deployment.

are transformation files and parameterization mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but here is a shot.

In Visual Studio 2010 Web.config transformations are executed based on the build configuration that is being used to publish/package. So in your example you stated that you created a config transform, Web.Release.config, and then you said "...with the intention of deploying mypackage.zip using a different configuration...". If you want to deploy a different configuration (i.e. not Release) then your config transformation will not kick in. You will need to create another web.config transformation which has similar content (or the same) as web.release.config.

Can you let me know if that helps, if not can you provide more details?